# Can steam create an overview of all my achievements?

Tags: steam, achievements

I play several games on Steam and I love the achievement system. It would be great to get an overview of all the achievements ever gained in Steam games. Does Steam support this? I haven't found such an overview.

If such a feature does not exist, I would already be happy with an easy way to calculate the sum of all my achievements automatically.

Edit: I stumbled upon an interesting website called [TrueAchievements](http://www.trueachievements.com) today. Unfortunately it only works for XBox-Achievements. Does anyone know of a similar service for Steam? This would solve my question right away. Implementing my own solution based on the links posted in the answers didn't work because the APIs are not sufficient for my needs.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/244381/130418 This was a good solution for me.

Comment: Trueachivements.com now has a sister site https://truesteamachievements.com/ for Steam games.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is also [playfire.com](http://playfire.com).  It tracks all of my X360 achievements, and there is the capability to track Steam, as well as PSN and XFire.  I do not have a steam account, but I like what they do with the XBox.  Might be worth trying out for Steam.

Comment: OK, it's already clear - that's exactly what I was looking for. Amazing platform, thanks so much!

Comment: Not a problem.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think that Steam provides such an overview.  However, Steam (and Steamworks) provide tools that could easily give the possibility to build it.

Check out the documentation and examples:

- https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/api
- http://steamcommunity.com/dev
- https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API

Some community platforms provide almost that kind of feature (but not exactly what you want, I think).  You should have a look at [Astats](http://astats.astats.nl/astats/index.php) (especially [this page](http://astats.astats.nl/astats/TopList.php?DisplayType=2)) and [Steamlevel](http://steamlevel.com/).

Steamlevel also says something interesting about Steam web API and achievements ([in its FAQ](http://steamlevel.com/faq#Q6)):

> **Can you show achievements?**
>
> I'd love to! Unfortunately Steam's Web API
>   for achievements isn't public for all games. I could list achievements
>   of Valve games, but achievements aren't readily available. I'm still
>   working on researching other ways to retrieve them, but don't hold
>   your breath.

For the records, most of those links came from this Steam's forum discussion: [Is there any site that will allow you to compare Steam collections?](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2238451)

Comment: +1: Thanks for the links, I will take a look at the possibilities of those APIs. The GetGlobalAchievementPercentagesForApp won't help, because it is not player specific. But maybe I will find the right calls in the rest of the documentation

Comment: You're right.  However I added some informations and references to my answer; hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

It's currently not possible to collect user achievement data wit the *"new"* [API](http://steamcommunity.com/dev/). **It's possible with the *"old"* [XML API](https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/community_data) though.**

It's basically just adding an uri parameter named `xml` with value `1` to a normal community uri. *(So for a community page of `http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/XYZ` this becomes `http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/XYZ?xml=1`)*

---

This is a sample *C#* implementation **(for demonstration purposes only!)** which exposes a `User.Load` method which takes the community id as a parameter. *(That id would be `XYZ` in the example above.)*

```
// System.dll
// System.Xml.dll
// System.Xml.Linq.dll
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

public class Achievement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Uri Icon { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri Logo { get; set; }
}

public class OwnedGame : Game
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Stats Stats { get; set; }
}

public class Stats
{
    public OwnedGame Game { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Achievement> Achievements { get; set;}
}

public class User
{
    private const string SteamCommunityProfileUriFormat = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{0}?xml=1";
    private const string SteamCommunityProfileGamesUriFormat = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{0}/games?xml=1";

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri Avatar { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OwnedGame> Games { get; set; }

    public static User Load(long id)
    {
        XDocument profileDocument = XDocument.Load(string.Format(SteamCommunityProfileUriFormat, id));
        XElement profileElement = profileDocument.Element("profile");

        User user = new User()
        {
            Id = long.Parse(profileElement.Element("steamID64").Value),
            Name = profileElement.Element("steamID").Value,
            Avatar = new Uri(profileElement.Element("avatarIcon").Value, UriKind.Absolute),
        };

        XDocument gamesDocument = XDocument.Load(string.Format(SteamCommunityProfileGamesUriFormat, id));

        List<OwnedGame> games = new List<OwnedGame>();

        foreach (XElement gameElement in gamesDocument.XPathSelectElements("gamesList/games/game"))
        {
            OwnedGame game = new OwnedGame()
            {
                Id = int.Parse(gameElement.Element("appID").Value),
                Name = gameElement.Element("name").Value,
                Logo = new Uri(gameElement.Element("logo").Value, UriKind.Absolute),
                User = user
            };

            XElement statsLinkElement = gameElement.Element("statsLink");

            if (statsLinkElement != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    XDocument statsDocument = XDocument.Load(statsLinkElement.Value + "?xml=1");

                    game.Stats = new Stats()
                    {
                        Game = game,
                        Achievements = statsDocument
                                    .XPathSelectElements("playerstats/achievements/achievement")
                                    .Where(achievementElement => achievementElement.Attribute("closed").Value == "1")
                                    .Select(achievementElement => new Achievement()
                                                                    {
                                                                        Name = achievementElement.Element("name").Value,
                                                                        Description = achievementElement.Element("description").Value,
                                                                        Icon = new Uri(achievementElement.Element("iconClosed").Value, UriKind.Absolute)
                                                                    })
                    };
                }
                catch (WebException)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            games.Add(game);
        }

        user.Games = games.AsReadOnly();

        return user;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
long id = ...
User user = User.Load(id);
int totalAchievementCount = user.Games.Where(game => game.Stats != null).SelectMany(game => game.Stats.Achievements).Count();
```

*Let me hope there are not too much typos in there :-)*

---

**Note:**

- As stated in the [Steam Web API Terms of Use](http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apiterms) **"you are limited to one hundred thousand (100,000) calls to the Steam Web API per day."**
- All *HTTP* responses of *steamcommunity.com* have a `Cache-Control: no-cache` Header.
- The [XML API](https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/community_data) is *"old"* and was meant to be fully replaced. **That means: XML-Data may be invalid and not available for all resources.** *(That's currently the case for Team Fortress 2 Stats)*
- You don't need an *API-Key* as it's the case for the *"new"* [API](http://steamcommunity.com/dev/).

Comment: I tried to add the xml=1 argument to my Steamcommunity uri, but sadly it didn't work.  Maybe you have to use the int id instead of the string id to make it work ?

Comment: @Anto Can you post me that uri?

Comment: Yep; but since my profile is private, I'm not sure you'll be able to test it: http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/antomrb?xml=1

Comment: Mhmmm...  Even when I'm logged in ?

Comment: @Anto Public example: http://steamcommunity.com/id/mikeb?xml=1

Comment: @Anton Its steamcommunity.com/profiles/ for IDs and steamcommunity.com/id/ for Custom Urls. Look at http://steamcommunity.com/id/antomrb?xml=1

Comment: It is possible to collect user achievement data with the Web API. It is still not possible to get unlock timestamps through the web api though. this still has to be done with community data.

Comment: This method no longer works.

Answer (score 6):

I found the website [SteamStats](http://steamstats.zr40.nl) which addresses my need. It tracks almost all steam games and calculates an overall score of all the achievements you have earned. The value of an achievement depends on the amount of achievements in the game and how many other players owning the game have completed that.

This mechanism is great because it puts a higher value on those achievements that are harder to get. I just tried the site for the first day and I like it already. Unfortunately the features are very limited but my basic requirements are met. The value system has some already obvious flaws. Skyrim, a game which you can play for over 100 hours easily without getting more than half of the achievements, is only worth less than 100 points if you get all the achievements. Other games like Q.U.B.E., where you can get all the achievements within 15 hours easily (once they are fixed) are worth about the same amount of points.

If anyone knows of a similar service with more features, I will accept their answer. Otherwise I will accept my own, because it currently fits what I am looking for best.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: The link is still dead.

Answer (score 6):

If you are above Level 10 on Steam then you get something known as an Achievement Showcase. This shows the number of achievements you have completed, percentage completed for all games that you have started and the number of games where you have got all achievements.

Something like this http://steamcommunity.com/id/rahulkadukar

Comment: +1 That's actually really nice, this feature is new to me. Do you know when this was introduced to steam?

Comment: This was recently introduced when they started the Trading Cards. So after every 10 levels you now have a showcase. Right now there are 13 showcases which can be selected. As I am Level 33 now, the 3 that I have displayed are Achievement showcase, Favorite Game and Game collector

Answer (score 5):

You can use a third party sites such as [MetaGamerScore.com](http://metagamerscore.com/).  These type of sites periodically scan your achievements, giving you a good overview of what achievements you have unlocked (or yet to unlock).

With regards to TrueAchievements, they have recently released a version dedicated to Steam achievements ([truesteamachievements.com](https://truesteamachievements.com/)).

Answer (score 4):

From the 100Pals Official Steam Achievement Hunting community, a list of all active achievement trackers and their creators:

Cross Platform

```
https://completionist.me/ luchaos
https://exophase.com/ x3sphere
https://metagamerscore.com/ primal_r
```

Steam

```
https://achievementstats.com/ ChrissyX, munky
http://astats.astats.nl/ Mytharox
https://steamhunters.com/ Rudey
https://steamladder.com/ Terry007, Florens
http://steam-tools.net/infograph Misteriosm
https://truesteamachievements.com/ Rich Stone
```

I personally use: cme (beautiful UI, detailed stats), AStats (point values/guides/leaderboards), MGS (cross-platform points/leaderboards), and SH (new tracker/good UI/leaderboards).  You can speak directly with all of the above developers on: https://www.discord.me/100Pals