# Is there a way to see all Steam achievements in one account?

Tags: steam, achievements

I want to check which of my games need the least achievements to achieve a perfect status.

The only way to see the game stats that I know of is to go to the games list from a player profile but that's too tedious, especially with over 250 games with varying degrees of play-times and achievement completion.

Comment: Hi, Dominici.  Answers belong as an answer, not as part of the question.  Since this is a duplicate, though, you should post your answer there.

Comment: Got it. Sorry. Should I link Colin D's answer in the other question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no Valve created way to do this from what I can tell.

However, using the steam APIs there is at least one community out there that allows players to do this named AStats.

The website is http://astats.astats.nl/astats/

specifically, you will need to go to  http://astats.astats.nl/astats/FindUser.php and put in your steam information. It will then put you in a queue for your profile and achievement information to be scanned.

Associated steam group with some more information: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/AStats

Answer (score 4):

You can use a third party sites such as [MetaGamerScore.com](http://metagamerscore.com/).  These type of sites periodically scan your achievements, giving you a good overview of what achievements you have unlocked (or yet to unlock).